# What do the numbered folders in ~/Library/Mail mean?

Tags: finder, mail.app, email

Bit of context: I deleted a mailbox (folder?) in Mail

[image]

Then a second later I realized I may have needed something from it and found that once you delete a mailbox [all content is lost forever](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mail/mlhlp1021/mac). So I went into my backups to see if I could find the mailbox/emails, and found this directory structure:

[image]

My question is: what is the logic behind these numbers? Specifically the 0-9 nested folders. If I want to navigate around this directory at all how can I use these numbers?

Comment: Did you know you can invoke Time Machine directly from inside Mail, so you can see a 'Mail view' of your history? Intentionally way too small to read… https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ3BR.jpg

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah I can't really see ... can you update and blackout the details? But anyways, when I invoke TM whilst Mail is open it just opens Finder at `~/Library/Mail` (as opposed to Mail which is what I guess you're trying to show)

Comment: I just tested iy myself on Monterey & it no longer works. APFS just hasn't been the success Apple would like us to think.

Answer (score 3):

This format is used in a number of Apple's own data structures. You'll also see it inside the Photo Library bundle, and in various temp folders.

I don't think there's any documentation for how it works, and really "it's not for browsing".

If you need to restore a mailbox, you can invoke Time Machine directly from the Mail app (using the TM menulet) to browse through past snapshots.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense (unfortunately). I know it wasn't the point of the question but just want to mention that the TM snapshot backups don't work for me. I guess that's because emails are downloaded on the fly to save space, or they're hidden in this obfuscated folder structure. E.g. the Dict.words folder has many emails in it in Mail, but in Finder the folder just holds a single `Info.plist`

Comment: @Bn.F76 Ask another question, explaining the problem with TM backups in Mail.app.

Answer (score 2):

It is a standard way to store many files in a file system. The issue is to keep tyhe number of files in a directory down as the low level code to find a file in a directory looks at each entry in the directory in a linear order, thus the speed of finding the file is proportional to the number of files in the directory.

How the files are split between directories is application dependent and there is no way to see from just the file system or Finder where an individual file will go. Thus the files are only usefully accessed by the application that writes them.

In this case it looks like each message is given an id that increases by one for each new message. This is reasonably common for Unix mail and nntp clients. Other apps e.g. Messages storing attachments generate hashs so the directories don't increase by one for each new attachment, this improves the spread of things into different directories.